# WebExtension: browser.tabs is undefined in FireFox (elementary OS)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to get access to the browser.tabs using an extension. My manifest.json currently includes these permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>",
  "activeTab",
  "tabs",
  "storage"
]
```

When I try to access `browser.tabs` I still get `undefined`.

I'm running Firefox 66.0.1 (64 bit) on the latest elementary os 0.5 - Juno.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction.

Cheers
Peter

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying?

Comment: Hello Paul, I've actually resolved the issue. I'll answer my own question to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the scope: I've attempted to access the tabs in the content script, while you can't access tabs from the content of the page (makes sense as you don't want to expose information about other sites). In the background script it works fine, as it runs on browser level.